# jQuery validation - validate actual data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate that the inputted data, contains a phrase, such as '%TAG%'.  So, if %TAG% is not present within the text, it doesn't validate.

Any ideas how I can do this using the jQuery validation plugin?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First Add a method to the validator

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkTAGPhrase", function(value, element) {
    return (/%TAG%/.test(value));
}, "Invalid.");
```

Next use this validation class on your input element

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" class="checkTAGPhrase">
```